# Using multiple jquery files on a single web page and ajax mini file upload form jqueries

Tags: jquery, file-upload, google-api

I want to use the mini ajax file upload form and the datepicker together in my web page, but when trying to use both of them the jquery clashes and does not works , only the uploader works but not the datepicker. I gave a try but in vain , the code is mentioned below:
The URL for ajax uploader which am using is : http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/
and together with it am using another jquery file for datepicker - jQuery UI 1.8

```
  <script>




$(function() {

$('#Date').datepicker();



    jQuery.noConflict(  )
            jQuery144 = jQuery
            console.log(jQuery144, jQuery)
</script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.full.min.js"></script>

<!--5 more files are included here for uploader-->


 <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery144(function($) {
                console.log("hello", $.fn.jquery)
            })
            jQuery(function($) {
                console.log("world", $.fn.jquery)
            })
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of noconflict etc is a bit weird. It looks like it would work, but i'd do it this way instead:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.uploader.js></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery191 = $.noConflict(true);
    jQuery191(function($) {
        console.log("hello", $.fn.jquery)
    });
    jQuery(function($) {
        console.log("world", $.fn.jquery)
    })
</script>
```